# System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable

Tags: vb.net

In my `MergeCollection` class i have `overide InsertItem` method to check for specific case. Nevertheless when it comes to the line `Items.Any(..` it throws me exception as below.

> ```
> System.ArgumentException: 'At least one object must implement IComparable.'
> ```

Merge class:

```
Public Class Merge
        Property Min As Integer
        Property Max As Integer?
        Property Value As Double

        Public Sub New(min As Integer, max As Integer?, value As Integer)
            Me.Min = min
            Me.Max = max
            Me.Value = value
        End Sub
End Class

Public Enum SortCriteria
        MinThenMax
        MaxThenMin
End Enum
```

Some comparer:

```
Public Class MergeComparer
        Implements IComparer(Of Merge)  

        Public SortBy As SortCriteria = SortCriteria.MinThenMax

        Public Function Compare(x As Merge, y As Merge) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of Merge).Compare
           'to be implemented
        End Function
End Class
```

Collection class:

```
Public Class MergeCollection
          Inherits Collection(Of Merge)

        Public SortBy As SortCriteria = SortCriteria.MinThenMax

        Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(index As Integer, item As Merge)
            if IsNothing(item.Max)
                If Items.Any(Function(myObject) IsNothing(Items.Max)) Then
                    Return
                End If
            End If
            MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
        End Sub   

        Public Sub Sort()
            Dim allItems = Items.ToArray()

            Array.Sort(allItems)

            For i = 0 To allItems.GetUpperBound(0)
                Items(i) = allItems(i)
            Next
        End Sub

        Public Sub Sort(comparison As Comparison(Of Merge))
            Dim allItems = Items.ToArray()

            Array.Sort(allItems, comparison)

            For i = 0 To allItems.GetUpperBound(0)
                Items(i) = allItems(i)
            Next
        End Sub

        Public Sub Sort(comparer As IComparer(Of Merge))
            Dim allItems = Items.ToArray()

            Array.Sort(allItems, comparer)

            For i = 0 To allItems.GetUpperBound(0)
                Items(i) = allItems(i)
            Next
        End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: @AndrewMorton ive mentioned where: Items.Any(..

Comment: Sorry, I meant at what point in time, like when you try to compile it/when it runs/something else, not on which line of code.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Now it is in Test project and when i debug and it reaches " If Items.Any(Function(myObject) IsNothing(Items.Max))" this pease of code exactly: "IsNothing(Items.Max)" it throws this error

Comment: What is the intent of `If Items.Any(Function(myObject) IsNothing(Items.Max))`? Is it meant to test if any of the items in the collection have no value for the Max property?

Answer (score 0):

The code asks for `Items.Max`. To find the Max value, it has to compare the Items to each other.

```
Public Class Merge
    Implements IComparable(Of Merge)

    Property Min As Integer
    Property Max As Integer?
    Property Value As Double

    Public Sub New()
        ' empty constructor
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(min As Integer, max As Integer?, value As Integer)
        Me.Min = min
        Me.Max = max
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Function CompareTo(other As Merge) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of Merge).CompareTo

        If other Is Nothing Then Return 1

        ' Could use
        ' Return (Me.Value).CompareTo(other.Value)
        ' instead of the following code...
        If Me.Value > other.Value Then Return 1
        If Me.Value = other.Value Then Return 0

        Return -1

    End Function

End Class
```

I guess that you want a different criterion for the comparison.

Comment: can it be done in MergeComparer and define it for instance in enum "CheckIfMaxNothingAlreadyExist" and tell this linq statment to use that comparmision somehow? If so can you show how could it be done?

Comment: @dev Sorry, I do not understand what you actually want to happen. Please edit your question to add some sample data and explain why inserting an item should do nothing in some cases.

Comment: your CompareTo body, can this method be not in Merge class itself but to be added to MergeComparer ?

Comment: @dev I would have to investigate the various overloads of Max... or you could. However, there is nothing wrong with not using Linq and just write the code for the mystery thing you want to check for with a loop.